# How to get statistics of torrent used in pcap file using bro IDS

Tags: pcap, network-traffic, bro

I have to analyze pcap file using bro IDS. I have done a lot of work but one thing is missing that is how can I found the states of torrent used. Is there some plugin in bro IDS that I have to enable ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an older Bit Torrent analyzer https://www.bro.org/sphinx/script-reference/proto-analyzers.html#bro-bittorrent.
But, unless this has changed within the last 6 months (check the commit logs in doubt), this analyzer is still not functional in a useful way.
You can give it a try and see what you get out of it. If you only want to know how much bit torrent traffic is in your pcap you might be able to extract that information from the logs. See if you can identify the torrent traffic in the logs and then you can use a simple script to get a summary.

Comment: Can you please guide, how I can enable this analyzer in bro ids

Comment: You have to load it using the @load statement:
http://try.bro.org/#/?example=basics-loading